# Request Entity to Large con Express sin solución

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, imagen, base64

Les traigo un problema el cual estoy hace varios meses sin poder solucionar.

Obtengo un error 413 Request Entity to Large tanto en local como en producción al envíar algunas imágenes codificadas en base64 por POST, PUT O PATCH.

Intenté configurar mi API en Express con bodyParser e incluso con express mismo, ya que a partir de la versión 4.16 en adelante, no es necesario. También intenté aumentar el CLIENT_SIZE_BODY de nginx en producción.

Las imágenes que intento envíar tienen un peso aproximado de 10 MB. Realmente no estoy entendiendo porque no logro resolver, necesito ayuda.

Dejo un fragmento de la configuración en express y captura de pantalla del error.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

let _express = null;
let _config = null;

class Server {
  constructor({ config, router }) {
    _config = config;
    _express = express()
      .use(router)
      .use(express.json({ limit: "2048MB" }))
      .use(
        express.urlencoded({
          limit: "2048MB",
          extended: false,
        })
      )
      .use(bodyParser.raw({type: '*/*'}))
      .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  }

  start() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      _express
        .listen(_config.PORT, () => {
          console.log(
            _config.APPLICATION_NAME + " API running on port: " + _config.PORT
          );
          resolve();
        })
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Server;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: consulta, que tan larga es la cadena generada por base64? y eso del limite de 2gb para que es?

Comment: Hola, bastante.. 42883 caracteres.

Comment: @PabloTedesco la solución no va en la pregunta, si no en la parte inferior que dice *Tu respuesta*, por favor edita, de paso remueve la leyenda de resuelto también por favor

Comment: Tal como te comentan, si has hallado la solución, publica una respuesta. Es el funcionamiento del sitio: **UNA** pregunta en el **área de preguntas** y una o más respuestas en el **área de respuestas**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El problema era que estaba sobre escribiendo el middleware de express en otro archivo. Básicamente realizaba una configuración de express al iniciar el servidor y otra en las rutas de la aplicación.

Como ven en la captura de pantalla, quite el middleware del script de inicio y lo agregue solo a las rutas que necesitaba extender el size body.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Evita adjuntar imágenes, estas deben ser solo ilustrativas al problema. Edita tu pregunta y adjunta el código 
necesario para entender mejor tu problema y/o respuesta.